# Azure DevOps Multi-Stage Pipelines. Running Throttled Amount of Stages

Tags: azure-devops

We have a Multi-Stage YAML Pipeline that consists of 20 stages and 4 Hosted Agents. 5 specific stages must not be running at the same time, these specific stages must not be running more than 2 at the same time. Is there a syntax for that?

Answer (score 1):

> Azure DevOps Multi-Stage Pipelines. Running Throttled Amount of Stages

You could try to set the same [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) for those 5 specific stages. then add a **Exclusive Lock** in `Approvals and checks` for this environment, which **limit access to this resource to only a single stage at a time**:

`Environments`-> Select the Environment-> `Approvals and checks`->`See all`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tried this approach and it doesn't work. The first Deployment Job tied to the Environment runs fine, however next Deployment Jobs are simply canceled as Exclusive Lock's description says: "Adding an exclusive lock will only allow a single run to utilize this resource at a time. If multiple runs are waiting on the lock, only the latest will run. All others will be canceled." https://i.stack.imgur.com/v87Rg.png